# SonarQube Rules appear to break analysis

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I have installed SonarQube with the basic settings and enabled all rules in the [C# Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin) (Currently version 5.5.0.479) and in doing so, my analysis breaks for some projects (some run fine). I couldn't find a way to find out which rules were breaking so I rather laboriously went through, enabling rules in a binary chop style in order to locate the offending rule. I found 2:

[image]

and:

[image]

When I enable either of these rules and run analysis, I get the error:

```
14:38:58.008 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
14:38:58.008 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Start pointer [line=65, lineOffset=0] should be before end pointer [line=65, lineOffset=0]
14:38:58.008    at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:145)
14:38:58.008    at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.newRangeValidPointers(DefaultInputFile.java:254)
14:38:58.008    at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.newRange(DefaultInputFile.java:238)
14:38:58.008    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.SensorContextUtils.toTextRange(SensorContextUtils.java:41)
14:38:58.008    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.protobuf.IssuesImporter.importMessage(IssuesImporter.java:54)
14:38:58.008    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.protobuf.IssuesImporter.importMessage(IssuesImporter.java:31)
14:38:58.008    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.protobuf.AbstractProtobufImporter.accept(AbstractProtobufImporter.java:49)
14:38:58.008    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.AbstractSensor.parseProtobuf(AbstractSensor.java:80)
14:38:58.009    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.AbstractSensor.importResults(AbstractSensor.java:70)
14:38:58.009    at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.executeInternal(CSharpSensor.java:114)
14:38:58.009    at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.execute(CSharpSensor.java:85)
14:38:58.009    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
14:38:58.009    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:57)
14:38:58.009    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:49)
14:38:58.009    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:78)
14:38:58.009    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:182)
14:38:58.009    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
14:38:58.009    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
14:38:58.009    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:247)
14:38:58.009    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:242)
14:38:58.009    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:240)
14:38:58.009    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:232)
14:38:58.009    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
14:38:58.009    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
14:38:58.010    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
14:38:58.010    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
14:38:58.010    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
14:38:58.010    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
14:38:58.010    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:115)
14:38:58.010    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:118)
14:38:58.010    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
14:38:58.010    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
14:38:58.010    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
14:38:58.010    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
14:38:58.010    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
14:38:58.010    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
14:38:58.010    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
14:38:58.010    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
14:38:58.010    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
14:38:58.010    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:110)
14:38:58.011    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:74)
14:38:58.011    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
14:38:58.011 ERROR: 
14:38:58.011 ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Running with `-X` didn't provide any more information.

Is this a bug with the plugin or the sonar-scanner or have I missed something?

I'm using [sonar-scanner 2.8](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner)

Comment: Could you tell me what's the version of MsBuild that you're using to build your project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in the C# plugin 5.4. 5.5 was supposed to fix it through this ticket: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCS-629, but it only happened for certain versions of MsBuilds (see https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/DOTNETLIB-10).

A new fix is on the way.

Comment: Ok, great. I shall wait for the new version before enabling these rules again. Thanks :)

Comment: This issue is also effecting Roslyn analyzers packaged as plug-ins using the SonarQube-Roslyn-SDK...

Comment: Is there a similar issue with the FxCop Plugin?

Comment: @Thomas Atwood can you tell me which Roslyn analyzer is affected? This specific issue is related to 0-length issue locations, which should ideally not happen in any analyzer. (The above two rules report file level issues in SonarQube, and we're "hacking" Roslyn to do it with 0-length issues locations)

Comment: @Rodders as far as I know, the FxCop plugin is not affected.

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam, I just went through and have debugged to see what rules are effected.  They are from Stylecop.Analyzers version 1.0.0:  SA1652 (Enable XML documentation), SA1633 (File must have header), SA1412 (Store files as UTF-8 with byte order mark), and SA1027 (Tabs must not be used).

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam, we just discovered another error with another rule...  which one, we don't know as we did not hit the rule with the previous project.  I will go through a diagnose...

Comment: @ThomasAtwood Thanks for investigating this issue. We wanted to fail fast, and therefore we hardcoded which rules can report file level issues. But this is definitely not working if we consider third-party analyzer packages. I created the following ticket to fix this issue: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/DOTNETLIB-11